Can you abbreviate an attributive phrase and then use the abbreviation as a noun and vice versa?

Over the period, there was an increase in the total length of UK calls using national and international line (NAIL) calls.

Here, the abbreviation is used as an attributive phrase. Then, I used it as a noun phrase:

People in the UK spent a total of 70 billion minutes on calls via NAILs.

I have another case of not using an abbreviation as its original form, which was described here.

You can do that if you have just explained what your abbreviation means, as in your first example. Since "nails" is also a common word, you have to be careful.

How you can use an abbreviation of a phrase further on Is unaffected by the fact that the phrase’s (first) occurrence—in which you introduce the abbreviation—happens to be an attributive use.

Thanks, guys. What about when they are a little different? In the link attached to this question, I first abbreviated "local fixed-line" as LFL. When I want to use the phrase "local fixed lines", is writing LFLs correct?

A question for you to think about. If you didn't use the abbreviation at all, but placed the full phrase into both sentences, would that change anything to do with the grammar of the sentences? Presumably not. So if the full phrase is used correctly, then replacing it with its abbreviation will also be valid.
